# How to insert alt tags dynamically in jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp

I want to insert an alt tag in the following lines of jsp code how do I accomplish this?

```
<li class="carousel-promo">
  <div>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${mediaType eq 3}">
    <dsp:valueof param="media.data" valueishtml="true"/>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${mediaType eq 1}">
    <dsp:getvalueof var="imgURL" param="media.url" />
    <img src='<dsp:valueof value="${imgURL}"/>' /> <br />
</c:when>   
</c:choose>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? Is it based on some condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im assuming you meant adding an alt attribute to the img-tag:

just do something like this when trying to set the alt attribute. this example sets the value of the variable fetched via the dsp-tag using media.description as a name of the property on your media object.

```
<c:when test="${mediaType eq 1}">
    <dsp:getvalueof var="imgAltText" param="media.description" />
    <dsp:getvalueof var="imgURL" param="media.url" />
    <img alt='<dsp:valueof value="${imgAltText}"/>' src='<dsp:valueof value="${imgURL}"/>' /> <br />
</c:when>
```

hope that helped....