# Alt Tags is not working for dynamic image tag

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, web-deployment

I am using dynamic images.That means inside image tag i am using dynamic link for src and dynamic text for alt.For src it is working fine,but in alt, i am not getting the text.Here is the example of my img tag.

```
<img style="top: 0px !important;" data-frame="<%=thumb%>" src="<%=image%>" alt="<%= advertiseObj.getAdTitle() %>" />
```

Comment: It seems similar problem like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248823/how-to-insert-alt-tags-dynamically-in-jsp, Just look at it

Comment: And what happens instead? Why are you still using scriptlets although they shouldn't be used anymore for years?

Comment: JB, i see what you mean with scriptlets, but honestly, for what he's doing, the only alternative would be a servlet for something as trivial as this, which is overkill, or jstl, which granted, isn't deprecated, but is just about as clean code wise.  **OP: Have you made sure your ad's title isn't returning an empty string or null? view the pages source and show us what's actually outputted by your servlet container**

Comment: Now this is solved.i was not getting the alt because of a javascript effect.

Answer (score 0):

Now this is solved.i was not getting the alt because of a javascript effect.

I am using that img for a gallery frame.So i am setting a frame for that gallery by jquery.So here was my old code.

```
(function ($) {
// custom image object
var gvImage = function (img) {

    this.src = { 
        panel: img.attr('src'),
        frame: img.data('frame') || img.attr('src')
    };
    this.scale = {
        panel: null,
        frame: null
    };
    this.height = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.attrs = {
        title: img.attr('title') || img.attr('alt'),
        description: img.data('description')
    };
    this.href = null;
    this.dom_obj = null;

    return this;
},
```

i have added something for alt also.it was just a hit and trail.But it worked for me.Here is my new code.

```
(function ($) {
// custom image object
var gvImage = function (img) {

    this.src = { 
        panel: img.attr('src'),
        frame: img.data('frame') || img.attr('src')
    };
    this.alt = { 
            panel: img.attr('alt'),
            frame: img.attr('alt')
        };
    this.scale = {
        panel: null,
        frame: null
    };
    this.height = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.attrs = {
        title: img.attr('title') || img.attr('alt'),
        description: img.data('description')
    };
    this.href = null;
    this.dom_obj = null;

    return this;
},
```